# White background in terminal (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: command-line, themes, 17.04, numix

I install "paper" theme and the terminal background change to white, I don't find out how to change it to dark. The same with Numix theme.
I want to use the colors of theme (not built-in schemes)
[image]

[image: I want it like this.]

I want it like second image.

Comment: in the terminal does Edit>Profile preferences under the color tab have "Use colors from system theme" checked? some themes don't 100% work, if that is checked and its still white you can customize the terminal colors/profile from that same place

Comment: I've tried that, but when "Use colors from system theme"  is active, it's just stays white. I rollback to Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine, tanks